# Generic AJAX function callback is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created generic ajax function to work with REST API.

I have written below code and it is working fine for at a time a single call. but if i make two different call then my success callback is overwrite with latest callback.

```
var ajax = {
    parameters: {
        url: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        loading: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        timeout: 30000,
        otherData: {}
    },
    callback: {
        success: null,
        error: null
    },
    get: function () {
        this.send('GET');
    },
    post: function () {
        this.send('POST');
    },
    del: function () {
        this.send('DELETE');
    },
    send: function (type) {
        self = this;
        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry|IEMobile/i)) {
            this.loadingIcon.show();

            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.dataType)) this.parameters.dataType = 'json';
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.contentType)) this.parameters.contentType = 'application/json';
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.loading)) this.parameters.loading = false;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.crossDomain)) this.parameters.crossDomain = true;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.async)) this.parameters.async = true;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.timeout)) this.parameters.timeout = 30000;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.callback.error)) this.callback.error = this.defaultError;

            return $.ajax({
                type: type,
                url: this.parameters.url,
                dataType: this.parameters.dataType,
                data: JSON.stringify(this.parameters.data),
                contentType: this.parameters.contentType,
                crossDomain: this.parameters.crossDomain,
                async: this.parameters.async,
                timeout: this.parameters.timeout,
                success: function (data) {
                    var args = arguments[2];
                    if (!self.isUndefined(self.callback.success)) {
                        if (self.isUndefined(self.parameters.otherData))
                            self.callback.success.call(this, data, args.statusText, args);
                        else
                            self.callback.success.call(this, data, args.statusText, args, self.parameters.otherData);
                    }
                    self.loadingIcon.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    xhrServerObj = xhr;
                    self.callback.error.call(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                    self.loadingIcon.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    },
    isUndefined: function (param) {
        return (typeof param == 'undefined' || param == null);
    },
    defaultError: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    },
    loadingIcon: {
        show: function () {
            if (self.parameters.loading) {
                console.log('Show loading....');
            }
        },
        hide: function () {
            if (self.parameters.loading) {
                console.log('Hide loading....');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am making ajax call using below

```
getAllStores(); 
getAllCategory();

function getAllStores() {
    var req = Object.create(ajax);
    req.parameters = { url: API + '/api/mobileapp/stores' };
    req.callback.success = successGetAllStores;
    req.get();
}
function successGetAllStores(data) {
    $.each(data, function (idx, d) {
        $("#StoreId").append($("<option value='" + d.StoreId + "'>" + d.StoreName + "</option>"));
    });
}

function getAllCategory() {
    var req = Object.create(ajax);
    req.parameters = { url: API + '/api/mobileapp/categories' };
    req.callback.success = successGetAllCategory;
    req.get();
}
function successGetAllCategory(data) {
    $.each(data, function (idx, d) {
        $("#CategoryId").append($("<option value='" + d.CategoryId + "'>" + d.CategoryName + "</option>"));
    });
}
```

if i am calling at a time only one function **getAllStores();** then on its success call back i am again calling **getAllCategory()** then this is working. not overwriting existing callback function.

Can you please help me how do i call multiple call using generic ajax call to handle individual callbacks.

Moreover i have tried using below but still it is overwritten latest callback.

```
function MyAjax() {
    this.parameters = {
        url: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        loading: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        timeout: 30000,
        otherData: {}
    };
    this.callback = {
        success: null,
        error: null
    };
    this.get = function () {
        this.send('GET');
    };
    this.post = function () {
        this.send('POST');
    };
    this.del = function () {
        this.send('DELETE');
    };
    this.isUndefined = function (param) {
        return (typeof param == 'undefined' || param == null);
    };
    this.defaultError = function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    };
    this.loadingIcon = {
        show: function () {
            if (self.parameters.loading) {
                console.log('Show loading....');
            }
        },
        hide: function () {
            if (self.parameters.loading) {
                console.log('Hide loading....');
            }
        }
    };
    this.send = function (type) {
        self = this;
        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry|IEMobile/i)) {
            this.loadingIcon.show();

            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.dataType)) this.parameters.dataType = 'json';
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.contentType)) this.parameters.contentType = 'application/json';
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.loading)) this.parameters.loading = false;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.crossDomain)) this.parameters.crossDomain = true;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.async)) this.parameters.async = true;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.parameters.timeout)) this.parameters.timeout = 30000;
            if (this.isUndefined(this.callback.error)) this.callback.error = this.defaultError;

            return $.ajax({
                type: type,
                url: this.parameters.url,
                dataType: this.parameters.dataType,
                data: JSON.stringify(this.parameters.data),
                contentType: this.parameters.contentType,
                crossDomain: this.parameters.crossDomain,
                async: this.parameters.async,
                timeout: this.parameters.timeout,
                success: function (data) {
                    var args = arguments[2];
                    if (!self.isUndefined(self.callback.success)) {
                        if (self.isUndefined(self.parameters.otherData))
                            self.callback.success.call(this, data, args.statusText, args);
                        else
                            self.callback.success.call(this, data, args.statusText, args, self.parameters.otherData);
                    }
                    self.loadingIcon.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    xhrServerObj = xhr;
                    self.callback.error.call(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                    self.loadingIcon.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Calling using below

```
var aj1 = new MyAjax();
    aj1.parameters = { url: API + '/api/mobileapp/stores' };
    aj1.callback.success = successGetAllStores;
    aj1.get();

    var aj2 = new MyAjax();
    aj2.parameters = { url: API + '/api/mobileapp/categories' };
    aj2.callback.success = successGetAllCategory;
    aj2.get();
```

Comment: save yourself a lot of code by learning how to use `$.extend()`

Answer (score 0):

Think I can see what your issue is - you're using the same object instance (ajax) as the prototype for each call to object.create (so they're using a shared resource) - so subsequent calls to the same thing stomp all over each other.

You could attempt to use $.extend when you do the object.create:

```
var clonedAjax = $.extend(true, {}, ajax);
var req = Object.create(clonedAjax);
```

However - a much cleaner way to approach this code would be to use ajax as a class and not use object.create at all.

```
function ajax(){
    this.parameters = {
        ....
    };
    this.get = function(){};
    .....
}
```

then

```
var req = new ajax();
```

---

**UPDATE:**  GOT IT WORKING:  It's a scope issue by the looks of it, here's a CUT DOWN working example of your approach - the crux is the assignation of "scb" when you send and use during "success".  **If this doesn't deserve a green-tick, nothing does ;)**:

```
var ajax = {
    parameters: {
        url: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        loading: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        timeout: 30000,
        otherData: {}
    },
    callback: {
        success: null,
        error: null
    },
    get: function ()
    {
        this.send('GET');
    },
    post: function ()
    {
        this.send('POST');
    },
    del: function ()
    {
        this.send('DELETE');
    },
    send: function (type)
    {
        self = this;
        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod|android|blackberry|IEMobile/i))
        {

            var scb = self.callback.success; // at the point where you SEND, make a note of the callback's that are attached and use during success
            //note - the callbacks that are attached when the send succeeds / fails can be different!


            return $.ajax({
                type: type,
                url: this.parameters.url,
                dataType: this.parameters.dataType,
                data: JSON.stringify(this.parameters.data),
                contentType: this.parameters.contentType,
                crossDomain: this.parameters.crossDomain,
                async: this.parameters.async,
                timeout: this.parameters.timeout,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var args = arguments[2];
                    if (scb)
                    {
                        if (!self.parameters.otherData)
                            scb.call(this, data, args.statusText, args);
                        else
                            scb.call(this, data, args.statusText, args, self.parameters.otherData);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    xhrServerObj = xhr;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

var get1 = Object.create(ajax);
var get2 = Object.create(ajax);

getGet(get1, cb1);
getGet(get2, cb2);

function getGet(req, cb)
{
    req.parameters = { url: "Req" };
    req.callback.success = cb;
    req.get();
}

function cb1()
{
    console.log("cb1");
}
function cb2()
{
    console.log("cb2");
}
```

Comment: Thank for explanation. I have tried both method but it is not working. 1. using $.extend i am getting an error "Cannot set property 'success' of undefined". 2. using class function it's behavior same like above prototype object, overwritten latest  callback function.

Comment: Updated to include a working example - if you don't mind a couple of suggestions - have a read up on jquery promises, $.extend and the truthy/falsey when it comes to evaluating if something's there or not (you don't need that "IsUndefined" function AT ALL).  Further, if you want to use this sort of approach, I'd suggest declaring "ajax" using a IEFE and closuring off the parameters, even better, use a class approach (function ajax(){}) rather than declaring a prototype and using object.create.  HTH!

Answer (score 0):

The most proper object oriented development in JavaScript makes use of the prototype of a function.

So first you create a function:

```
Foo = function()
{
};
```

Then you add functions to its prototype as so:

```
Foo.prototype.Blah = function()
{
   // here you can access 'this'
};
```

Now Blah() is a function of the object/class named Foo. You can instantiate using the new keyword and call the function as expected:

```
var f = new Foo;
f.Blah();
```

The prototype can also be used for variable members. You have 2 types of variable members in JavaScript: static and non-static. If you use a compiler such as the closure compiler from Google, you can also *pretend* to define public, protected, and private members, but in the final version everything is public anyway.

```
Foo.static_value = 123;  // initialized on load, common to all objects
Foo.prototype.value = 5; // initialized to 5 on construction
```

In most cases you want to use static variables when they are constant.

There is, however, a pitfall with variable members. If you define an object or an array, these do NOT get copied so the same reference will appear in all the objects. In most cases the following is wrong:

```
Foo.prototype.ary = [1, 2, 3];
Foo.prototype.obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
```

The way to go around this problem is to initialize the arrays and objects in the constructor which goes like this:

```
Foo = function()
{
  this.ary = [1, 2, 3];
  this.obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
};
Foo.prototype.Blah = function()
{
   this.ary.push(17); // not common to all objects of type Foo
};
```

Then the declaration of those members uses null:

```
Foo.prototype.ary = null;
Foo.prototype.obj = null;
```

That way you avoid the problem of a reference to another object which would be common to all your objects.

You may also want to make use of a namespace, which is just a variable, to avoid potential problems later. Say your library is call lib, you could write:

```
var lib = {};
```

Then prefix that to all the Foo definitions as in:

```
lib.Foo = function() { ... };
```

There are also ways to derive one object from another ("extends") but that's even more advance!